# How to make content center of horizontally equally divided views in ConstraintLayout android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, chain, android-layout-weight

I need to divide 3 views equally horizontally and the content of the views to be centered. I tried using the link: https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb

But I'm unable to make the views center and equally divided.
I also tried using `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight` but that didn't work. Then I tried using chain which is given below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="81dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View 1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_8"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvINameValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_4"
            android:text="Sachin"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvName" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_4"
            android:text="Dey"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvINameValue"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvName" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewDividerLeft"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/divider_blue"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view1"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View 2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/view3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRollNo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
            android:text="Roll No"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryDark"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_8"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRollNoValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16"
            android:text="123"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvRollNo"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewDividerRight"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/divider_blue"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view2"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View 3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_8"
            android:text="Address"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAddressValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_4"
            android:text="Titan 123"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvAddress" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually are on the right path , You need [Chains](https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb) in Constraint Layout..

1. Place the buttons(without constraints) and then select Chains>Create Horizontal Chains..(Also there is further option to customize your chains , packed, scattered etc)
2. Again select the 3 elements and align top.

Make sure that if you're trying to chain.. There isn't any existing constraint on them